# Calculating Gravitational Waves Given Boundary Conditions

Tags: general-relativity, gravitational-waves

How can I calculate the gravitational waves emitted by a system in which the initial and final angular momentums are known? Can you provide me with an explicit example?

Say the system starts at rest with angular momentum $L_{initial}=L_{\hat{x}}$ undergoes asymmetric acceleration
and rotates and stops at $L_{final}=L_{\hat{y}}$.

I have only solved the linearized gravity equations for the vacuum solution so far, so I have no clue how to start.

1. How can I do this calculation when I work with the full non-linear non-vacuum Einstein Field Equations?
2. If my metric doesn't satisfy the Lorenz gauge/de Donder condition, how do I proceed?

Comment: What do you mean by calculating gravitational waves (GW)? Do you mean calculating quantities like mass-loss of the source due to outgoing GW, quadrupole moments, or conserved quantities of system as a whole etc?

Comment: @KP99 The general form of the gravitational wave in the non-linear EFE (ex: in linearized gravity it would be the metric perturbation $h_{\mu\nu}$ in the metric $g_{\mu\nu}=\eta_{\mu\nu}+h_{\mu\nu}$).

Comment: It's not clear to me, how I would arrive at a wave solution in the form of d'Alembertian acting on a metric without the lorenz/de Donder condition and a linear perturbation $h_{\mu\nu}$.

Comment: For non linear behavior in vacuum, here are few articles you can refer to: [1] https://royalsocietypublishing.org/doi/10.1098/rspa.1961.0202  [2] https://royalsocietypublishing.org/doi/10.1098/rspa.1962.0161#pane-pcw-details [3] https://royalsocietypublishing.org/doi/10.1098/rspa.1966.0197

Comment: @KP99 Thank you so much! These papers were very insightful! I think I should be able to do the above calculation now. :)

Comment: Cool! But you have to be careful about which definition for angular momentum you choose to set the boundary conditions. Angular momentum of a system in curved space-time is not a well understood concept

Comment: @KP99 by choosing the definition of angular momentum carefully, are you referring to having the correct Killing Vector Field so that angular momentum is conserved?

Comment: In general, you won't have any KVFs, in that case notion of momentum and angular momentum becomes ambiguous which is primarily due to non-local behavior of energy-momentum of gravitational field. There are number of definitions for angular momentum (see : https://arxiv.org/pdf/1001.5429.pdf). In absence of cosmological constant, Penrose's quasi-local momentum-angular momentum definition seems to encapsulate a lot of other definitions